# asp.net controlIDs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandle);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandle);
    function beginRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
        //Do something when call begins. 

        document.getElementById("btn1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("btn2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    function endRequestHandle(sender, Args) {
        if (document.getElementById('<%= hfResultsCount.ClientID %>').value != 0) {
            document.getElementById("btn1").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("btn2").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<br><b><center><font style='font-family:Haettenschweiler; font-size:xx-large'>No data found, please try again.</b></font></center>";
        }
    }
</script>
```

and the code for btn2:

```
 <input type="button" runat="server" name="btn2" id="btn2" value="New Window"
 style="visibility:hidden;font-weight:bold;width:200" onclick="window.open('http://microsoft.com');" />
```

I am using Js to show/hide buttons (needs to be done like this so don't suggest otherwise) and while `btn1` is `asp:button` it always works but for `<input type=button>` I keep getting this error

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined
```

The way to fix that for `btn1` was to just add `ClientID=Static` but how to do that for `<input>` button? (I do not want to make it asp:button since I need it to not postback)

Everything is in an UpdatePanel with ClientID=Static also.

I know its something to do with the IDs and the master page since it works fine on a page on its own.

Comment: No btn1 works fine. the error is from btn2 I need to fix that one

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to access button on server side then you should not put runat="server", This will make your script to find button and it will not generate error.

```
<input type="button"  name="btn2" id="btn2" value="New Window"
 style="visibility:hidden;font-weight:bold;width:200" onclick="window.open('http://microsoft.com');" />
```

OR, If you want to make runat="server" you can access it like this

```
document.getElementById(<%= btn1.ClientID %>).style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: I need to add it so that I can modify the onclick= part from the code behind. I believe its just a matter of picking up the wrong IDs thanks to the master page but not sure how it picks them up

Comment: Then you can access it by document.getElementById(<%= btn1.ClientID %>).style.visibility = "visible"; , also update my answer

Comment: Thanks it was due to `(<%= btn1.ClientID %>)`

Answer (score 0):

After the page rendering go to view source and check how ID is appearing with master page you may get some idea

It might not be btn directly....master_xxx

Comment: name is `ctl00$MainContent$btn2` and Id is `MainContent_btn2`

Comment: Hope you got the answer with the ClientID                                                                       document.getElementById(MainContent_btn2)... ll also work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
<input type="button" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
name="btn2" id="btn2" value="New Window"
style="visibility:hidden;font-weight:bold;width:200"
onclick="window.open('http://microsoft.com');"/>
```

or, if you don't need to access the control in your code behind :

```
<input type="button" name="btn2" id="btn2" value="New Window" 
style="visibility:hidden;font-weight:bold;width:200"
onclick="window.open('http://microsoft.com');"/>
```